# how to make scanner with delimeter switch at an if depending on which delimeter was hit

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a text file that has things like,
Tom, Kelly, Jane:0, Matt:2, Jon

so in this place //if(******) I want to use the list.add that is there for Tom,Kelly, Jon and I want to use a scanned int from the file in the place of 0 for Jane,Matt.  I am not sure that  the Delimiter is the right choice and I know that having both of those Scanners in there is not correct either.  Please point me in the right direction.

```
public static Picker fromFile() throws FileNotFoundException 
{
   ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
   Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(new File("Names.txt"));
   diskScanner.useDelimiter(", |:");

   while (diskScanner.hasNext()) {

        //if(******)
        list.add(new Student(0, diskScanner.next()));// or list.add(new Student(diskScanner.next(), diskScanner.next()))
   }
   list = Order.arrange(list);

   Picker pick = new Picker(list);
   return pick;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it like so:

```
Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(new File("Names.txt"));
diskScanner.useDelimiter(",");

while (diskScanner.hasNext()) 
   {
    String n = diskScanner.next();

    if(n.contains(":"))
       {
        int i = n.indexOf(":");
        list.add(new Student(Integer.parseInt(n.substring(i+1)), n.substring(0,i)));
       }
    else
        list.add(new Student(0, n));
    }
```

Untested, so use with caution. You can often trip yourself up by seeking an overly elegant solution. Just get all the strings between the commas, then do any extra parsing.

Comment: This really looked like it was going to work but it does not like (int)n.substring(i+1).  it throws an error of incompatible types: java.lang.Srring cannot be converted to int.  Back to the drawing board.

Comment: I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java  and it was int foo = Integer.parseInt("1234");

Comment: @Chad Yeah sorry about that, it's been a while since I've coded in Java. I've edited my answer. If you feel that it is now satisfactory, I would appreciate it if you would mark it as accepted.